# How to get argument count in OCaml?

Tags: ocaml, argc

In my exploration of learning OCaml I am wondering how you would correctly get `argc` i.e., the argument count from the command line to check if enough arguments were specified.

From looking at the `Sys` module I am not seeing a function that will get `argc`.

I have tried

```
let argc_length = Sys.argv.length(Sys.argv);;
```

Yet, this does not work.

How would you get the argument count from the command line in OCaml?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Sys.argv` is an array of string.
To get its length : `Array.length Sys.argv`

So to fix your code :

```
  let argc = Array.length Sys.argv;;
```